# Jquery delay() and fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

I've been stuck to one little problem, I want to fadeIn specific block when I'm clicking on other block, then wait for 2.5 sec and fade specific block out. Here is the code I have so far:

```
$('button.other-block').click(function () {
    $(this)
    .find('.specific-block')
    .fadeIn()
    .delay(2500).queue(function() {$(this).fadeOut(1600, complete)});
});
```

fadeIn just goes fine and delay function runs fine too. But fadeOut seems to be not working (it doesn't matter if I will change it to .fadeOut(1600) or just .fadeOut() )
Where is the problem could be?

Here is the full code, since there is much more simplified version above.

HTML:

```
<div class="account-edit-group">    
                    <input type="text" value="" class="account-edit-field">
                    <div>
                        <button class="account-edit-field-save"> </button><button class="account-edit-field-cancel"> </button>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="account-edit-field-warning"><span class="w-text">Error! You can enter no more than 30 symbols</span></div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$('button.account-edit-field-save').click(function () {
      var checklength = $(this).parent().parent().find('input.account-edit-field');  
        if(checklength.val().length > 30)
        {
        $(this)
        .parent()
        .parent()
        .find('.account-edit-field-warning')
        .fadeIn()
        .delay(2500).queue(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(1600, complete).dequeue(); 
        });     
        }
        if(checklength.val().length <= 30)
        {
        $(this)
        .parent()
        .parent()
        .removeClass('acc-edit-f')
        }
      });
```

So JS is checking which button was clicked, and if button-save was clicked - it checks value of the field above. If there is more than 30 symbols - it will show the error message. Which I need to fadeIn first, show for a little, and then fadeOut. That's the problem, it won't fade out and I don't know why.

Comment: Please post your HTML too..

Comment: You want me to post full code for this issue? It's big, is it ok?

Comment: Just post the .specific-block element

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can wait for the fade in to finish first by passing in a callback like this:

```
$('element').fadeIn(function () {
   // Fade in complete
});
```

When the fade in is complete, you can continue with the delay and fade out.

```
$('button.other-block').click(function () {
   $(this)
     .find('.specific-block')
     .fadeIn(function () {
        $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut(1600, complete);
     });
});
```

If it doesn't work then switch over to Mootools ;)

**EDIT:** working example http://jsfiddle.net/tbleckert/RcL5y/

Comment: It doesn't work too... Well, yeah, looks like I will need mootools.

Comment: Just to point out for those reaching @tbleckert's answer by google, `complete` refers to a function that is run when the fadeOut has been completed

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$('button.other-block').click(function () {
    $(this)
    .find('.specific-block')
    .fadeIn()
    .delay(2500).fadeOut(1600, complete);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[.dequeue()](https://api.jquery.com/dequeue/)** here:

```
$('button.other-block').click(function () {
    $(this)
    .find('.specific-block')
    .fadeIn()
    .delay(2500).queue(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(1600, complete).dequeue(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the callback function in `.fadeIn()`:

```
$(this).closest('.account-edit-group').find('.account-edit-field-warning')
       .fadeIn('normal', function(){
          $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut();
       });
```

Although this should work:

```
 $(this).closest('.account-edit-group')
        .find('.account-edit-field-warning')
        .fadeIn()
        .delay(2500)
        .fadeOut();
```